# XML Serialization Not populating the array

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, .net-4.6.2

I am trying to serialize the below XML. But the section "Keys" are not getting populated and its coming as null in the serialized object.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Golden>
<SecType>
    <ID>New</ID>
    <Count>1</Count>
</SecType>
<Request>
    <Action>New</Action>
    <Keys>
        <Key>
            <ReferenceType>AAA</ReferenceType>
            <ReferenceValue>1111</ReferenceValue>
            <Description></Description>
        </Key>
        <Key>
            <ReferenceType>BBBB</ReferenceType>
            <ReferenceValue>22222</ReferenceValue>
            <Description></Description>
        </Key>
    </Keys>
</Request></Golden>
```

I am trying to create a custom class object for further use. Please see my code below.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRootAttribute("Golden")]
public class Process
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("SecType")]
    public SecType secType { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute("Request")]
    public Request request { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRootAttribute("SecType")]
public class SecType 
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute("Count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRootAttribute("Request")]
public class Request
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("Action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute("Keys")]
    public Keys keys { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[XmlRootAttribute("Keys")]
public class Keys
{
   [XmlArray("Keys")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Key", typeof(Key))]
    public Key[] key { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRootAttribute("Key")]
public class Key
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("ReferenceType")]
    public string ReferenceType { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute("ReferenceValue")]
    public string ReferenceValue { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


    string sPath = @"C:\Test\ConsoleApp1\test.xml";
    Process proc = new Process();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Process));
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sPath);
    proc = (Process)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
```

I mainly referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document). But it's not working in my implementation.Thanks for you help

Comment: I think you missed `</Golden>` at your XML?

Comment: </Golden> Tag is there. But it's not showing there.

Comment: I removed the Keys class and add this in the request class:    [XmlArray("Keys")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Key", typeof(Key))],        public Key[] key { get; set; } and it started getting the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the Key Element :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication142
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Process));
            Process proc = (Process)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRootAttribute("Golden")]
    public class Process
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("SecType")]
        public SecType secType { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute("Request")]
        public Request request { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRootAttribute("SecType")]
    public class SecType 
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute("Count")]
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRootAttribute("Request")]
    public class Request
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("Action")]
        public string Action { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("Keys")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Key")]
        public Key[] keys { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRootAttribute("Key")]
    public class Key
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("ReferenceType")]
        public string ReferenceType { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute("ReferenceValue")]
        public string ReferenceValue { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


}
```